# Segmentation Fault with Push Operation on Template Stack Objects

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault, stack

I am teaching myself about data structures, and I have been working on a Stack class to that can make a stack of any object using templates. However, when I run the program, it has a segmentation fault. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but I think it is happening when push is called.

Here is the code for my push function:

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T const& element) {
    top++;
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        stackArray[top] = element;  
    } else {
        throw 1;
    }     
}
```

And here is my main:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stack.h"

int main() {
    try {
        int strSize;
        cout << "\tEnter a size for the string stack: ";
        cin >> strSize;
        Stack<string> strStack(strSize);

        cout << endl;

        int iSize;
        cout << "\tEnter a size for the int stack: ";
        cin >> iSize;
        Stack<int> intStack(iSize);

        cout << endl;

        // Problem code here? These are for debugging
        strStack.push("This is a string.");
        intStack.push(10);


        cout << "\tstring stack: ";
        cout << strStack.getStackArray()[0];
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\tint stack: ";
        cout << intStack.getStackArray()[0];
        cout << endl;


    } catch (std::exception const& ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But if it's a segfault, it must have something to do with how I am allocating memory. Here is my constructor and destructor for Stack:

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(int size) {
    setSize(size);
    stackArray = new T[size];
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack() {
    stackArray = nullptr;
    delete [] stackArray;   
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and have been trying to debug this for hours. I've looked at other stack overflow threads, but I'm not sure that I've found anything that addresses my issue entirely. I feel like I am missing something that should be obvious.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `top` is not initialized. Print `top` on console when push is called, I am sure it is not 0 when first push is invoked.

Comment: What is `top`? Please give a [mcve]

Comment: @rafix07 Wow. I'm a real fool for not seeing that. Well, that's the answer. Thank you! I hadn't initialized top. Now that I did that, the segfault is gone.

Comment: You are setting `stackArray` to null *before* deleting its contents on the deconstructor